# how can i append these entries to a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
number = int(input("Enter the number of parcels you want to input: "))
width = int(input("Enter the width (cm)of the parcel: "))
length = int(input("Enter the length (cm)of the parcel: "))
height = int(input("Enter the height (cm)of the parcel: "))
weight = int(input("Enter the weight (kg) of the parcel: "))

width_list = []
length_list = []
height_list = []
weight_list = []
parcel_number = []

parcel_number.append(number)

if width > 80 or width < 1:
    print("Only widths between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
elif height > 80 or height < 1:
    print("Only heights between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
elif length > 80 or length < 1:
    print("Only lengths between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
elif weight > 10 or weight < 1:
    print("Only allowed weights between 1-10 kg")
else:
    print("Parcel is acceptable")
```

First i asked the user to add the measurements of the parcel. Then i needed to check if each parcel was between the correct size 1-80 cm and the weight between 1-10 kg, and then if the user input a measurement beyond the limit it needs to print the mistake. And if the parcel is acceptable i should append each measurement to the lists below, but i dont know how to do it, with the acception of the parcel_number. And if possible can you help me put the code in a loop so i run it the number of times appended to the parcel_number list? Thanks!

Comment: You should check out the docs for python for-loops! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
c=0
number = int(input("Enter the number of parcels you want to input: "))
width_list = []
length_list = []
height_list = []
weight_list = []
parcel_number = []

parcel_number.append(number)
while c < number:
   width = int(input("Enter the width (cm)of the parcel: "))
   length = int(input("Enter the length (cm)of the parcel: "))
   height = int(input("Enter the height (cm)of the parcel: "))
   weight = int(input("Enter the weight (kg) of the parcel: "))


   if width > 80 or width < 1:
       print("Only widths between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
   elif height > 80 or height < 1:
       print("Only heights between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
   elif length > 80 or length < 1:
       print("Only lengths between 1-80 cm is acceptable")
   elif weight > 10 or weight < 1:
       print("Only allowed weights between 1-10 kg")
   else:
       width_list.append(width)
       length_list.append(length)
       height_list.append(height)
       weight_list.append(weight)
       print("Parcel is acceptable")
   c += 1
print(width_list)
print(length_list)
print(height_list)
print(weight_list)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of parcels you want to input: 2
Enter the width (cm)of the parcel: 33
Enter the length (cm)of the parcel: 55
Enter the height (cm)of the parcel: 33
Enter the weight (kg) of the parcel: 2
Parcel is acceptable
Enter the width (cm)of the parcel: 45
Enter the length (cm)of the parcel: 34
Enter the height (cm)of the parcel: 23
Enter the weight (kg) of the parcel: 3
Parcel is acceptable
[33, 45]
[55, 34]
[33, 23]
[2, 3]
```

I just simply use the python list `append` function and then i create a variable  named c and assign it to 0 and then make a while loop that checks if `c` is smaller than `number` if it is the code runs and at the end of the code i add 1 to c and then it checks if `c` is still smaller then number if it isn't it does n't run the code again